# How to encrypt URL and restrict direct download a file in PHP and/or .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, encryption

I have to restrict direct downloading any file inside the directory in the webserver. Also, should allow to download through server script generated encrypted URL.

*For example*,

Directory path of the file: `/home/downloads/password.txt`

URL: `http://www.sitename.com/downloads/password.txt`

Direct access to the URL must be restricted. But, should allow to download through server generated encrypted URL.

*For example*,

```
<a href="http://www.sitename.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.php">Download</a>
```

The actual server script to control downloads will be,

```
http://www.sitename.com/private/download.php
```

But, direct access to that URL (*shown above*) should be restricted. So, that there will be no permanent link to access directly.

Comment: I tried to use the previously posted questions,
[How to allow downloading files with PHP, but deny direct access to directory listings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957720/how-to-allow-downloading-files-with-php-but-deny-direct-access-to-directory-lis), [PHP: How can I block direct URL access to a file, but still allow it to be downloaded by logged in users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl)

Comment: i think you misunderstood. SO is here to help you with problems in your code, not to create your software concepts for you. so: what have YOU tried to achieve this, not counting asking other people to do it for you?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann You have misunderstood. I know to restrict direct file access inside the directory using .htaccess.  Also, I know to restrict direct PHP file access inside the directory from the URL. But, I have to generate random URL or encrypted URL (not permanent) for each downloads only through accessing the web page.

Comment: so yes - what have you tried to achieve the generation of those random URLs? what is the actual code you've written that you have problems with?

Comment: I can able to encrypt or generate URL. But, it will deny access to actual URL because it is restricted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101852/discussion-between-ak-se-and-franz-gleichmann).

Comment: Your best bet is to save the original file above the webroot (not publicly-accessible) and have your script stream that file.

Comment: [MikeRockett](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1626250/mike-rockett) Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

[Encryption is almost always a bad choice for URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Instead of `http://www.sitename.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.php` just make it `http://www.sitename.com/download.php?onetimecode=[32 hex characters]` and make sure you use [`bin2hex(random_bytes())`](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) to generate the token.

Store the actual data you're trying to protect **outside of your document root** to prevent direct object access, only allow a valid one-time code to supply access to this code.